# Encontrar números cuadrados perfectos C++

Tags: c++

Como puedo encontrar los números cuadrados perfectos solamente con suma, nada de multiplicación?.
No encuentro manera de resolverlo.

```
int Arreglo[15];
void Llenar() {
    int suma=1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        while (Arreglo[i] <= i) {
            suma = i*i; //No tiene que ser por multiplicación, sino sumando hasta encontrar los cuadrados. 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36...
            break;
        }
        Arreglo[i]=suma;
    }
}
void Imprmir() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        std::cout<<Arreglo[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
int main() {
    Llenar();
    Imprmir();
}
```

Comment: Si estás usando `std::cout` tu código no es C. Por favor, si tu pregunta es sobre [tag:c++] no etiquetes la pregunta como [tag:c]. C y C++ son lenguajes diferentes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tal y como ha mencionado [RodrigoBurgosMella](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/231269/2742), una multiplicación no es más que una sucesión de sumas, así que puedes simular la multiplicación repitiendo sumas:

```
int repite(int n, int i)
{
    return n + (i == 1 ? 0 : repite(n, i - 1));
}
```

La función anterior te suma el número del primer parámetro tantas veces como indique el segundo parámetro, así que si queremos hacer un cuadrado, debemos llamar a dicha función con ambos parámetros iguales:

```
int al_cuadrado(int i)
{
    return repite (i, i);
}
```

Con esto, podemos rellenar una formación con cuadrados:

```
int cuadrados[15]{};
std::generate(std::begin(cuadrados), std::end(cuadrados),
              [i = 2]() mutable { return al_cuadrado(i++); });
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4i7NhGMMVBV8wI7L).

Comment: Gracias amigo. Como haría para encontrar los cúbicos? 8, 27, 64...

Comment: @Mauricio una multiplicación no es más que una sucesión de sumas, así que puedes simular la multiplicación repitiendo sumas.

Answer (score 8):

la multiplicación aritmética, corresponde a una repetición de sumas, así es que puedes hacer una función que simule esta cálculo:

```
int multiplicacion(int multiplicando, int multiplicador){
  int producto=0;
  int indice;

  for(indice=1;indice<=multiplicador;indice++){
     producto += multiplicando;
  }
  return producto;
}
```

ahora, para el caso de tu aplicación, deberias usar la llamada, utilizando el mismo numero:

```
resultado=multiplicacion(2,2);
resultado=multiplicacion(3,3);
```

obviamente, lo puedes colocar en un buqle que vaya hasta una cantidad consultada al usuario.
espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias amigo. Como haría para encontrar los cúbicos? 8, 27, 64...

Comment: tendrias que simular la potenciación, "x" elevado a "y", donde "x" seria un valor variables e "y" un 3.

Answer (score 2):

Aquí dejo mi solución al problema

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
long cubo( const int x );

int main(){
// Constante numércia con la cantidad de numeros cubicos a calcular
const int tamanio = 15;

// Numero a partir del cual inicia la serie
int numero = 2;

// Arreglo para almacenar los cubos
int cubos[ tamanio ] = {0};

// Recorremos los primeros n numeros y calculamos sus cubos
for( int i = 0; i < tamanio; ++i )
{
    // Calculamos el cubo de 'numero' y lo guardamos en el arreglo 'cubos',
    // despues 'numero' se incrementa en uno para calcular el siguiente cubo
    cubos[ i ] = cubo( numero++ );

    // Imprimemos el numero calculado y lo separamos con un espacio
    cout << cubos[ i ] << " ";
}    


}

long cubo( const int x )
{
// variable para ir almacenando la suma, de tipo long para 
// poder almacenar numeros grandes
long n = 0;

// Itera el numero de veces que se debe multiplicar
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++ )
{
    // Calcula la multiplicaion por medio de sumas
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++ )
    {
        n += x;
    }
}

// devuelve el cubo de 'x'
return n;
}
```